# What is the best free open source CMS (content management system) solution?

Tags: content-management-system

I want to convert a website to use a Content Management System for updating a large number of content pages for a website.  The current website is mostly ASP.NET, but I am considering converting to PHP if it means I will have better integration with the "CMS of choice" in the market.  I have heard of Joomla! and other CMS' but I would like some answers to which ones are considered better.  Features that I need to support are custom sidebar and tab menus (with expandable javascript drop downs for example).  Can anyone tell me of a good solution?

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times. You should have probably searched the bunches of questions already posted for this (see the Related links list to the right side of the screen).

Answer (score 4):

You should look at [opensourcecms.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com/). It's a site that hosts demos for the majority of open source CMS's out there in both PHP and ASP.NET. You can try each one out and read the features and reviews. It's a good way to find one that meets your needs without actually installing them.

Answer (score 3):

[Joomla](http://www.joomla.org) and [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) are your most common and popular PHP based CMS solutions.

On the .NET side I would suggest only [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com). The amount of development that goes on in that CMS is second to none and there is a huge marketplace for content, modules, themes, etc. There is pretty much everything available in DNN to meet your potential needs.

Comment: I'd highly advise avoiding Joomla, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Ironically, I've had more problems with Drupal in the past than Joomla.

Comment: DotNetNuke is very nice, I've been working with it for a short while and so far I've been incredibly impressed.

Comment: I found Joomla to be quite a poor solution.  Unfortunately I can't really recommend anything better.

Answer (score 2):

The "best" CMS really, really depends on your requirements.

I will say that Joomla is pretty much typical PHP spaghetti, and I hate it, but it might work for you.

Kentico (a .NET CMS) is a pretty decent one that I've deployed a few times.  Microsoft CMS is supposed to be decent, I haven't tried it though.

Without knowing specifically your requirements, I find it impossible to give a solid recommendation, though.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work with these applications yet, but AFAIK [TYPO3](http://typo3.org/) and [ezPublish](http://ez.no/de/ezpublish) (both PHP) are considered much more professional than e.g. Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) has a long history, proven track record of success (many high profile use cases, including the Obama campaign, Mozilla Firefox, and MTV in the UK), and a boatload of free [modules](http://drupal.org/project/Modules) and [themes](http://themegarden.org/drupal6/) so you can start somewhere good. Drupal is also highly customizable in terms of how data is stored in terms of content types. Drupal has excellent [consulting and contracting](http://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+consulting&sourceid=navclient-ff&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1B3GGGL_enUS309US309) help.

Joomla is a strong second, but a quick look at [Joomla criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla#Criticism) on wikipedia, and I think the choice gets much clearer. Two out of the three [criticisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal#Criticism) of Drupal on wikipedia are that it's too complicated, which is really a subjective matter as compared to the shortcomings of Joomla.

Answer (score -1):

If web development is a hobby for you, then use an open source CMS such as those mentioned.  If it is your profession, consider working towards writing your own that meets your needs.  The first few will likely be a little rough, but in the long run it can prove very fulfilling and must more customizable than anything off the shelf.

Writing your own also forces you to consistently expand your skills and learn the intricacies of the programming language.